# How to solve this double integral with integration by parts?

Tags: integration

I am reading an academic paper which seems to skip some steps (as academic papers tend to do).

Here is the problem (in simplified terms):

Given

$$\tau(z) = \int_0^zf(y) \; dy$$

and

$$ G(z) = f(z)E(z) $$

find

$$\iint G(z).$$

The authors then state that they "integrate twice and integrate by parts" to obtain:

$$\iint G(z) = \int_0^z (z-y)E(y) \;d\tau(y)$$

Can anyone explain how they reached this answer? And what does the $d\tau(y)$ represent? We are now integrating with respect to $\tau(y)$?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because $G$ is a function of $f$ and $E$, it first helps to write $f$ as a function of $\tau$. This can be written in the form $f(y) = \frac{d\tau(y)}{dy}$.

Bang this into your integral of $G$, and see where you can get to.